# How to extract line number of an error in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I’m writing a library validating XML bassed on guidelines in XSD.
If the validation is unsuccessful I need to return all the error messages with corresponding line numbers. It’s important to remember that attachments shouldn’t be counted. I’m at a complete loss on how to get the correct line number of XML file.
Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: What errors are the schema check giving?

Comment: Much more information required. Are you using one of the well-known validating XML parsers, or are you implementing the validation logic yourself? What do you mean by 'all the error messages?' Why is this important? What options have you already explored?

Comment: Why are you writing such a library? Doesn't it already exist?

Comment: I implemented something similar to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: That's a really tough task. You need a lexer and a parser and really good knowledge of the XML specifications. This is far from trivial and way beyond what we can answer on SO. AFAIK, using ANTLR will give you line numbers.

Comment: Don't invent your own.  Either use what is built into .NET, or Saxon (which is pretty much maintained by the guys who define the XML standards).

Comment: To everyone telling me that I shouldn't be writing such a library: I was tasked with it as an intern.

Comment: Did your manager/mentor/supervisor really specify that you must not use any code libraries? Think carefully about your answer. You may want to ask some questions about the requirements before jumping into coding.

Comment: [XmlValidatingReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader) class has `LineNumber` property. [XmlSchemaValidationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationexception) class also has `LineNumber` property.

Answer (score 0):

A new line starts at a `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Linux and `\r` on Mac. To get the line number, start counting at 1 (for humans, that's a good starting point) and increase the number whenever you found a line ending.

When you have an error in your XML, you typically get the position of character. Now you compare that position in the file to the positions of the new line characters.

That's how you get line numbers. Other than that, XSD validation is far from trivial, you need a lexer and a parser and probably write a grammer. To do so, you need very good knowledge of [the XML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) and related material.